# Write Excel data directly to OutputStream (limit memory consumption)

Tags: java, excel

I’m looking for a – simple – solution to output big excel files. Input data comes from the database and I’d like to output the Excel file directly to disk to keep memory consumption as low as possible. I had a look to things like Apache POI or jxls but found no way to solve my problem.

And as additional information I need to generate .xls files for pre 2007 Excel, not the new .xlsx xml format. I also know I could generate CSV files but I’d prefer to generate plain Excel…

Any ideas ?

I realize my question isn't so clear, I really want to be able to write the excel file without having to keep the whole in memory...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842244/writing-large-excel-spreadsheets

Comment: I saw this question, even if the title is quite similar I'm only interested in writing excel files, no need to read them. And I'm specifically looking for a way not to hold the whole excel file in memory...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way to do this efficiently is to use *character*-based CSV or XML (XLSX) format, because they can be written to the output **line by line** so that you can per saldo have only one line at once in the memory all the time. The *binary*-based XLS format must first be populated **completely** in memory before it can be written to the output and this is of course memory hogging in case of large amount of records.

I would recommend using CSV for this as it may be more efficient than XML, plus you have the advantage that the any decent database server has export capabilities for that, so that you don't need to [program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755509/jsp-page-without-html-code-for-exporting-data-to-excel-sheet/1755605#1755605)/[include](http://www.google.com/search?q=java+csv+api) anything new in Java. I don't know which DB you're using, but if it were for example MySQL, then you could have used [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) for this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think I will go for CSV till my company migrates to a newer Office version and then continue with xlsx. You know about a library to generate xlsx line by line ?

Answer (score 2):

No idea for generating a real XSL file. But you can directly write a **HTML** file, or a zip stream containing an [OPenDocument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument) spreadsheet (I guess MSExcel can read this later format)

Comment: HTML is an extremely bad idea. Don't do that. Excel will messup it on edit/save and the latest versions will complain about unsupported file format. Use XLS/XLSX/CSV only.

Answer (score 2):

[JExcelAPI](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) is often recommended as a more memory efficient alternative to Apache POI.